# How to get Past 12months with year from current date

Tags: javascript, jquery, date

I want to show the past 12 months but year is not appending with the list

```js
var theMonths = new Array("January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December");
var today = new Date();
var aMonth = today.getMonth();
var i;

for (i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
  document.writeln(theMonths[aMonth] + '<br>'); //here you can do whatever you want...
  aMonth++;
  if (aMonth > 11) {
    aMonth = 0;
  }
}
```

How can I get the past 12 months with year from current month.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to include the year with the output date then the simplest method is to add 1 month to the current date within your loop. You can then retrieve the month and year from that date within the loop, something like this:

```js
var theMonths = new Array("January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December");
var now = new Date();

for (var i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
  var future = new Date(now.getFullYear(), now.getMonth() + i, 1);
  var month = theMonths[future.getMonth()];
  var year = future.getFullYear();
  console.log(month, year);
}
```

Note that this loop, which is copied from your question, gets months in the future yet your description states you want to retrieve passed months. In that case you'd simply need to loop from `0` to `> -12` instead, using `i--`.

Comment: Doen't OP want the past months and you're getting the next 12? Maybe i'm wrong.

Comment: That's true, although I followed their loop structure in the OP. If the requirement is to go in to the past you'd need to loop from `0` to `-12` instead. I'll update the answer, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to track down the current month, then the month before it etc. judging from your sentence:

> How can I get the **past** 12 months

Try replacing the code in your loop with this:

```
aMonth--;
if (aMonth < 0) {
    aMonth = 11;
}
```

If that's not the case please elaborate your desired result in more details :)

Comment: `...show the past 12 months but *year is not appending with the list*` The issue seems to be that the year is not included in the date.